# handling nested Json structure

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

suppose we have following json structure :

```
{
    "positions": {
        "node": "abc"
    }
    "submissions" :{
        "submissionOffsets":[
        {
            "attributeName": "sample1",
            "attributeValue": 1224
        },
        {
            "attributeName": "sample2",
            "attributeValue": 1224
        },
        {
            "attributeName": "sample3",
            "attributeValue": 1224
        },
        {
            "attributeName": "sample4",
            "attributeValue": 1224
        }
        
    }
}
```

and we want to read "submissionOffsets" and extract attributeName and attributeValue based on attribute name for example "sample1" and expected structure should be  **in case of Match**

```
{
    "positions": {
        "node": "abc"
    }
    "submissions" :{
        "submissionOffsets":[
        {
            "attributeName": "sample1",
            "attributeValue": 1224
        },
        {
            "attributeName": "sample2",
            "attributeValue": 1224
        },
        {
            "attributeName": "sample3",
            "attributeValue": 1224
        },
        {
            "attributeName": "sample4",
            "attributeValue": 1224
        }
        
    },
"attributeName": "sample1",
"attributeValue": 1224
}


**Incase of No Match**

{
    "positions": {
        "node": "abc"
    }
    "submissions" :{
        "submissionOffsets":[
        {
            "attributeName": "sample1",
            "attributeValue": 1224
        },
        {
            "attributeName": "sample2",
            "attributeValue": 1224
        },
        {
            "attributeName": "sample3",
            "attributeValue": 1224
        },
        {
            "attributeName": "sample4",
            "attributeValue": 1224
        }
        
    },
"attributeName": null,
"attributeValue": 0.00
}
```

This has to be done in dataframes

I was trying with dataframes i exploded submissions.submissionOffsets , then checked for attribute name and value, but this giving one column, i have to join that back to original dataframe.

Comment: If any json property contains `null` spark will remove & it will not be available in your final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` higher order function to filter specific attribute from nested array json.

`inline` or `inline_outer` - to explode array values.

Below is sample code

```
scala> val df = spark
.read
.option("multiLine", "true")
.json(Seq(data).toDS)

df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [positions: struct<node: string>, submissions: struct<submissionOffsets: array<struct<attributeName:string,attributeValue:bigint>>>]

scala> df.show(false)
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|positions|submissions                                                           |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{abc}    |{[{sample1, 1224}, {sample2, 1224}, {sample3, 1224}, {sample4, 1224}]}|
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+


scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- positions: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- node: string (nullable = true)
 |-- submissions: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- submissionOffsets: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- attributeName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- attributeValue: long (nullable = true)


scala> 
// filter higher order function to filter nested json array values / attributes
// inline_outer is to explode array values

df
.selectExpr(
    "*", // to select all columns from the dataset / dataframe
    "inline_outer(filter(submissions.submissionOffsets, i -> i.attributeName == 'sample1')) as (attributeName, attributeValue)"
)
.toJSON.show(false)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"positions":{"node":"abc"},"submissions":{"submissionOffsets":[{"attributeName":"sample1","attributeValue":1224},{"attributeName":"sample2","attributeValue":1224},{"attributeName":"sample3","attributeValue":1224},{"attributeName":"sample4","attributeValue":1224}]},"attributeName":"sample1","attributeValue":1224}|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks it works , but can we make some changes, that it should return rest of datastets incase of now match?

Comment: I didn't get you. can you please update you question with expected result in case of no match ?

Comment: Let's Soppose if i change filter criteria to sample5 df
.selectExpr(
    "*", // to select all columns from the dataset / dataframe
    "inline(filter(submissions.submissionOffsets, i -> i.attributeName == 'sample5')) as (attributeName, attributeValue)"
)  Then I expect values of Positions returned and then submissions, and then attrbuteName and attrbuteValue as blank, but positions and submissions should have there values as is

Comment: got it. In case if filter is not matched what will be the default values for `attributeName` & `attributeValue` ?

Comment: updated code. added `inline_outer` function to keep structure same in case of filter is not matched.

Comment: Thanks it works, how can we update values as 0 instead of null

Comment: yes sure, can you help me in populating 0 instead of null in attributeName and attributeValue

Comment: sure, can you please update you question with above usecase ?

Comment: you mean new question ?

Comment: no, in this question only below you can add above use case.

Comment: how can we aggregate extracted values incase of multiple matches ?

Comment: Ravish, I didn't get you can you please create new question with sample input and expected output.. or you can send me same in mail